# Connect to Remote Firebird DB from AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebird, aws-glue

**Attempt 1: AWS Glue**
In AWS Glue, we are trying to run an ETL job against a remote Firebird DB.
We start by: AWS Glue > Databases > Connections > "New Connection"

1. Connection Type: JDBC
2. jdbc:firebirdsql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3050/C:\program files (x86)\folder\database\dbname.FDB
3. We chose a VPC, Subnet and Security Group.
   Completed.

When we "TEST Connection", I get Error, check logs. When go to check logs, nothing exists. (although access to write logs exsits)

I'm essentially looking for the correct steps to connect Firebird as a datasource for ETL in AWS Glue or AWS Glue DataBrew.

[image]

**Attempt 2:**
I also tried using Python locally:
conn = firebirdsql.connect() which gives us a No connection could be made because target mahcine actively refused it (When firewall was off)

```
>>> conn = firebirdsql.connect(
...     host='108.xxx.xxx.xxx', 
...     database="c:/program files (x86)/folder1/database/datab.fdb",
...     user='sysdba',
...     password='masterkey',
...     timeout=50
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Scripts\lib\site-packages\firebirdsql\__init__.py", 
line 95, in connect
conn = Connection(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Scripts\lib\site-packages\firebirdsql\fbcore.py", line 
641, in __init__
    self.sock = SocketStream(self.hostname, self.port, self.timeout, 
cloexec)
  File "C:\Users\Scripts\lib\site-packages\firebirdsql\socketstream.py", 
line 46, in __init__
    self._sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 844, in 
create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 832, in 
create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and specifically include any errors you get, with stacktraces (Java) or tracebacks (Python). As it stands, it sounds as if your database is not running, or not accessible on the IP address you're trying to use, or not listening on port 3050.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Added more context above. DB is running as its a production application db. A front end app is connecting via port 3050 already. So, we opened the firewall and this was the error received in python.  AWS doesnt connect at all and throws no error for me to see in log.

Comment: The error means that the port isn't open (at least not from AWS), or blocked by a firewall. Maybe your Firebird server isn't bound to this IP address (e.g. setting `RemoteBindAddress` in firebird.conf has an explicit IP), or maybe you have overlooked a firewall (e.g. on the machine itself).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Bottom line, we have the Firebird Server running on a Windows Server. We do have an application that pulls from the DB.  This is a vendor of ours. Now, as a client using the application, I want to get the data from the database and run analytics on it. But Firebird is not great to do this. So i want to get all the data from Firebird into another system. What are the options here? AWS Glue will not connect as per above, and Python will not either.  @Mark suggested RemoteBindAddress, but isnt it already bound to the application, therefore cannot bind to another IP?

Comment: @user10951045 No, the `RemoteBindAddress` configures that address on which the server is listening. The default is 0.0.0.0, which means "all IP addresses of this host", but if it is set to for example 127.0.0.1, the server is only accessible on `localhost`. The connection refused error from your Python application indicates that you're specifying the wrong ip-address (or hostname) and/or the wrong port number (or maybe that a firewall is blocking access).

Comment: @Mark, so if we have the server admin change the RemoteBindAddress to 0.0.0.0, and then i use the python script above (the host is the IP address of the server), I should be able to connect? Else, remove firewall and then connect?

Comment: Probably, but otherwise I would recommend asking on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support), because Stack Overflow is not really a good venue for troubleshooting problems.